# Apache Tiles 3 JSP Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, apache-tiles

I have a strange issue with Apache Tiles 3. It was setup and working fine before but the project under went some refactoring and now it's completely broken. It always returns a 500 internal server error with a stack trace (included below). The project name, folder structure, some folder names, and some file names were changed, to meet standards handed down for the project.

What is strange is the paths are absolutely correct, which seems to be what it's complaining about. The following line I don't understand at all. Any ideas?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/views/tiles/shared/header_jsp (wrong name: org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/Views/Tiles/Shared/Header_jsp)
```

layout file

```
<!-- standard template -->
<definition name="base" template="/WEB-INF/views/templates/default.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value=""></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="header"
        value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/shared/header.jsp"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="content" value=""></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="footer"
        value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/shared/footer.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>

<!-- Dashboard -->
<definition name="home/index" extends="base">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Home"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/home/home.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>
<!-- End Dashboard -->

<!-- User -->
<definition name="user/login" extends="base">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Login"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="header" value=""></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="content"
        value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/user/login.jsp"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value=""></put-attribute>
</definition>

<definition name="user/index" extends="base">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Users"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="content"
        value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/user/index.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>

<definition name="user/add" extends="base">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Users - Add"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/user/add.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>
<!-- End User -->
```

stack trace

```
2014-02-16 23:01:57,777 DEBUG [DispatcherServlet] - Could not complete request
org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/templates/default.jsp'.
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:399)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:145)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/templates/default.jsp'.
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:61)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:267)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/views/tiles/shared/header.jsp'.
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:61)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:125)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.templates.default_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f1(default_jsp.java:261)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.templates.default_jsp._jspService(default_jsp.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/views/tiles/shared/header_jsp (wrong name: org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/Views/Tiles/Shared/Header_jsp)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: Seems like `header.jsp` failed to compile. Do you have any other exception messages that would indicate that?

Comment: Hmmm, that was the full dump. I didn't see anything else in the logs. However /WEB-INF/Views/Tiles/Shared/Header.jsp was the full path before, now its /WEB-INF/views/tiles/shared/header.jsp. Does this mean its still looking for the old path? Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/views/tiles/shared/header_jsp (wrong name: org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/Views/Tiles/Shared/Header_jsp)

Comment: That's possible. Try cleaning your tomcat server working directory.

Comment: It was related to Tomcat and JSP cache. However strangely cleaning tomcat through Eclipse and deleting the work directory contents did nothing, I had to delete tomcat and re-download it. However that did the trick. If you write an answer I will accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the exception stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/views/tiles/shared/header_jsp (wrong name: org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/Views/Tiles/Shared/Header_jsp)
```

It seems like the compiled class file for the `header.jsp` JSP file is missing. This can mean that the Servlet container failed to generate it and that can happen for a number of reasons.

From hints in your comments, it seems that it might just be a file naming issue. You can probably resolve it by cleaning tomcat's working directory and your web application's working directory.